# Driver error : DTM to raster using GDAL_GRID

Tags: gdal, dem, error, personal-geodatabase

I am looking to interpolate a DTM (eventually over 4,000 DTMs) that is in a personal geodatabase format.  I would like to do this in as few step as possible, eventually writing a batch script to do them all.

I was under the impression that I could use gdal_grid to accomplish this but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access
Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=17509200.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default drive
r specified
Unable to open input datasource "17509200.mdb".
Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (
*.mdb);DBQ=17509200.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default drive
r specified
```

after using the following command:
    `gdal_grid 17509200.mdb test1.tiff -zfield ELEVATION -ot Float64 -l 17509200`

I am using GDAL 1.9.2 on a Windows machine.

My version does support reading of "Pgeo" so I thought GDAL would be able to use the .mdb as an input, and output a raster. But apparently I have to specify a driver (I'm not sure why it can't use PGeo?).  I have seen on other forums Linux users using various MDB driver extensions.  Does anything exist similar to that for Windows? Or can I specify the PGeo driver in GDAL as it is now? How do you specify a driver in GDAL?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use ogrinfo on the mdb alone to check that you can access that correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the ogr driver with an odbc driver.  See:

http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html

and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the -l option as the name of the layer within the geodatabase.  Also try running oginfo on the .mdb file to see if it can read anything.

Comment: I get an identical error message as the one above with ogrinfo.